# Django - Order_by a queryset more than once

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to re-order my queryset after ordering it once. Is it possible?

Here is my `get_queryset` method:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    id_ordered_logs = BatchLog.objects.filter(batch__user__isnull=False)\
    .order_by('-batch_id').distinct('batch_id')
    return id_ordered_logs
```

I want to order this list by their `created_at` fields, this is what I want to do:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    id_ordered_logs = BatchLog.objects.filter(batch__user__isnull=False)\
    .order_by('-batch_id').distinct('batch_id')
    return id_ordered_logs.order_by('-created_at')
```

I'd like to know if this is possible.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I think it's legal to do this, but the first order_by() clause I believe will just be ignored.  It's not actually running the query until you start requesting data, so at the point of return, it's still forming the query.  So the result and query will be the same with or without the first order_by().

Comment: @saquintes that returns an error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`

Comment: Ah, didn't pick up the effect DISTINCT had on the order-by.  Your question makes it sound like you are asking a more general question.  I might make a point to highlight that you are trying to do this with `distinct` which has a some caveats at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct, which I think is what you are really trying to ask about getting around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by this implementation:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    id_ordered_logs = BatchLog.objects.filter(batch__user__isnull=False).order_by('batch_id').distinct('batch_id')
    return BatchLog.objects.filter(id__in=id_ordered_logs).order_by('-created_at')
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this

```
id_ordered_logs = BatchLog.objects.filter(batch__user__isnull=False)\
    .order_by('-batch_id', '-created_at').distinct('batch_id')
```